# Pandas: Drop row based on a different rows value

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I've got a pandas dataframe that has info on tracks and how they were matched. There's a whole bunch of columns but I want to drop rows based on these columns:

```
     ID          Hard_Match  Soft_Match
75   205487000      False       True
91   205487000      False       True
47   205487000       True      False
0    209845000       True      False
62   210842000       True      False
81   212085000      False       True
96   229132000      False      False
90   229550000      False      False
66   229758000       True      False
```

If want to remove "soft matched" rows if there exists a "hard matched" row with the same ID:

```
for each row in dataframe:
    if row[hardmatched] == True somewhere else:
       remove row
    else:
       keep row
```

So in the above example 205487000 would be removed in index 91 and 75 and kept in index 47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC then the following does what you want:

```
In [112]:
ids = df.loc[df['Soft_Match'] == True, 'ID'].unique()
ids

Out[112]:
array([205487000, 212085000], dtype=int64)

In [113]:    
hard_matches = df.loc[(df['Hard_Match'] == True) & df['ID'].isin(ids), 'ID']
hard_matches

Out[113]:
47    205487000
Name: ID, dtype: int64

In [116]:
df.loc[~((df['ID'].isin(hard_matches)) & (df['Hard_Match'] == False))]

Out[116]:
           ID Hard_Match Soft_Match
47  205487000       True      False
0   209845000       True      False
62  210842000       True      False
81  212085000      False       True
96  229132000      False      False
90  229550000      False      False
66  229758000       True      False
```

So this first looks for the IDs for when 'Soft_Match' is `True`, we then find where the 'Hard_Match' is `True` and where the ID matches those IDs, we then filter out the rows where the ID matches and where 'Hard_Match' is `False`